# What is the difference between this queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have query which is  dynamically update to a migration file,When I execute the exact query  it throw this error,I have try it in many but nothing is working! `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type':'text','filed_name':'Ture_st  aare','order':'5','values':['Mr','Mrs','Miss']' at line 1`

```
Query 1
// working
DB::statement("Insert Into custom_fields_configure (`table_name`, `configure`, `filed_name`, `module_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at` ) values ('ads','test','cf_Ture_staare',22,now(),now());");

Query 2 
// Not working
DB::statement("Insert Into custom_fields_configure (`table_name`, `configure`, `filed_name`, `module_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at` ) values ('ads','{'type':'text','filed_name':'Ture_staare','order':'5','values':['Mr','Mrs','Miss'],'datalenght':'5'}','cf_Ture_staare',22,now(),now());");
```

How can resolve this?

Comment: You seem to have single quotes in a string intended to be a value.  Just double up the single quotes so SQL will interpret them correctly.

Comment: just add "\" before "'" or replace single quote with double quote

Comment: Yes its works for me, thanks! @GordonLinoff ,@Newbee Dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to insert this value as a string.

{
    'type': 'text',
    'filed_name': 'Ture_staare',
    'order': '5',
    'values': ['Mr', 'Mrs', 'Miss'],
    'datalenght': '5'
}

This seems a bit off to me as it looks like most of the text going inside it (like 'type': 'text', 'datalenght': '5') should not be there. Still if you need to put the same as one value then you need to ADD "\" so that the same can be taken as a single string value.

Hope this helps !